# Java type inference not working as expected

Tags: java, type-inference

I seem to have managed to break Java's type inference, with the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    final VirtualFS vfs = new VirtualFS();
    vfs.addDirHandler(vf -> {
        // top level directory only,
        // return a list of all tags
        return Arrays.stream("@tag_one @tag_two @tag_three".split(" +"))
                .map(str -> (vf.getName() + str))
                .map(str -> new VirtualFile(str)) // <-- here
                .toList();
    });
    ...
}
```

The above works fine, but if I change the marked line to:

```
                .map(VirtualFile::new) // <-- here
```

... then it refuses to compile (although the IDE doesn't complain about it). I can also fix the problem by adding a `(String)` cast to the previous .map operation.

The `.getName()` method in `VirtualFile` returns a `String`. Java version is 17, my IDE is Intellij IDEA. Like I said, I can solve the problem with a cast, but I'm curious as to what's going on to confuse the type inference.

The compiler error I get is:

```
java: incompatible types: invalid constructor reference
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

Minimum reproducible example:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.*;

public class VirtualFile
{
    private final String name;

    public VirtualFile(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName () { return this.name; }

    private static class VirtualFS
    {
        public void addDirHandler (Function<VirtualFile, List<VirtualFile>> fn)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final VirtualFS vfs = new VirtualFS();
        vfs.addDirHandler(vf -> {
            // top level directory only,
            // return a list of all tags
            return Arrays.stream("@tag_one @tag_two @tag_three".split(" +"))
                    .map(str -> vf.getName() + str)
                    .map(VirtualFile::new)
                    .toList();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the compile error? I think it would add some value to the question

Comment: As neither `VirtualFile` nor `VirtualFS` are part of the Java 17 SDK, please add where you use that classes from. (dependency + import or your own relevant parts of the implementation)

Comment: @Sweeper minimal reproducible example provided. As a stand-alone project, with no dependencies etc, that still exhibits the problem discussed.

Comment: @cyberbrain the classes are my own, but the problem persists with almost all the functionality trimmed out; see example above.

Comment: The code compiles on Java 21, so I suspect this might just be a compiler bug.

Comment: Code also compiles in Java 8 (with minimal adaption to change the `.toList()` to a `.collect(Collector.toList())`, so I also think it is a compiler bug. BTW it also works if you declare the type of `vf` as `(VirtualFile vf)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the compiler bug [JDK-8268312](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8268312), where if you call a method taking a `Function` like (`Stream.map`) in the lambda parameter of another method that takes a `Function` (like `addDirHandler`), the type information of the former call gets lost.

This is fixed in Java 20.